# How to upgrade the Version of Spring 3.1.x to 3.2 via Pom.xml in Spring STS

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I just currently tried up upgrade from Spring 3.1.x to Spring 3.2.0 via my pom.xml file and now i"m getting the following exception. What else must I do besides update the version of  the pom.xml file in STS?

```
2012-12-14 15:53:43 -0500 - org.springframework.core.env.ConfigurableEnvironment.merge(Lorg/springframework/core/env/ConfigurableEnvironment;)V<P><span class="captionText">For reference, the Error ID is b5f5e10f-612f-4f54-a36d-f65d6d7b9496.</span> - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.env.ConfigurableEnvironment.merge(Lorg/springframework/core/env/ConfigurableEnvironment;)V
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.setParent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:395)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:585)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:269)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:163)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1200)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:827)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:129)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:647)
    at blackboard.tomcat.valves.LoggingRemoteIpValve.invoke(LoggingRemoteIpValve.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
    at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:776)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:705)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:898)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: See here for notes on migrating (including covering this issue with the spring-context dependency I think): http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/migration-3.2.html

Comment: Please check that you have updated both spring-core and spring-context dependecies.